# Patter in XML for a string

Tags: xml, xsd-1.1

I want to write a pattern for element photo that the name of the photo end with **png** or **jpg**
I tried this code but it doesn't work properly

```
 <xs:simpleType name="Photo">

    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[a-z]([.png] | [.jpg])"/>
    </xs:restriction>

</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: No, that would match "+png" for example - the dot needs to be escaped, otherwise it matches any character. And I suspect ".png" shouldn't be valid, either.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, you're right. I didn't test it properly since it was only a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used regular expressions within XSD before, but assuming it's just a normal regular expression, you want:

```
[a-z]+\.(png|jpg)
```

That means:

- At least one (but optionally many) a-z characters
- Then a period
- Then `png` or `jpg`

Note that you might want to allow other characters in the first part, e.g. digits and upper case letters. You should consider non-ASCII characters too.

Comment: how can I do it with digits and upper case letters `[a-z]|[A-Z][0-9]+\.(png|jpg)` ? is that right?

Comment: @Jo101: Not quite: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(png|jpg)`. (That's basically "one or more letter/digit" followed by . and then png or jpg.)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using XSD 1.1, you could use an **assertion** to be slightly more explicit with the validation logic. Much easier to create, and much easier to maintain going forward.

Check it out.

**XSD 1.1**

```
<xs:simpleType name="Photo">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:assertion test="ends-with($value, '.jpg') or ends-with($value, '.png')"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```